# Upload Image Custom Field

Tags: field, image, upload, custom

Is there any "Upload Image" custom field in craft so that I will be able to make my images editable. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the [Assets Field](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields)